# HashTable to Lwuit Table

Tags: java, json, java-me, hashtable, lwuit

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Dynamic table in lwuit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992755/dynamic-table-in-lwuit)
>   [HashTable to Lwuit Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074809/hashtable-to-lwuit-table)

Please give me Some example 
After parsing a JSON String I want to put it in a HashTable,From the HashTable I get the value and put it in a LWUIT table,every thing will be dynamically ,there is no hardcore value.